# How to set local biases in caffe and torch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, torch

When convoluting a multi-channel image into one channel image, usually you can have only one bias variable(as output is one channel). If I want to set local biases, that is, set biases for each pixel of the output image, how shall I do this in caffe and torch?

In Tensorflow, this is very simple. your just set a bias matrix, for example:

data is `25(height)X25(width)X48(channels)`

weights is `3X3(kernel size)X48(input channels)X1(output channels)`

biases is `25X25`,

then,

```
hidden = tf.nn.conv2d(data, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')    
output = tf.relu(hidden+biases)
```

Is there a similar solution in caffe ortorch?

Answer (score 3):

For caffe, here is a scale layer post: [Scale layer in Caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410996/scale-layer-in-caffe). Scale layer can only provide one variable bias.
The answer is Bias layer. bias layer can have a weight matrix, treat it as biases.

For torch, torch has a nn.Add() layer, almost like the tensorflow's tf.add() function, so nn.Add() layer is the solution.

All these have been proved by actual models.

But still thank you very much @Shai

Comment: You are obviously right `"Bias"` layer is the right way to go. However, if you pay close attention, `"Scale"` layer with `bias_term: true` has a `"Bias"` layer build into it, thus allowing for a 2D ("local") bias terms.